# Why isn't my heading element text being centered as expected?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**CSS PART**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  body {
    h1.h1 mb-0 text-gray-800 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

**Bootstrap Part**

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="overflow: hidden;">

          <!-- Page Heading -->
          <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">

            <h1 class="h1 mb-0 text-gray-800" >View Services</h1>

          </div>
```

**how can i make the h1 text at center with this content?**

Comment: `.h1 mb-0 text-gray-800` is not a valid CSS selector.

Comment: @isherwood what will be valid selector in this above example?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to target (do you really want to  _only_ center gray headings?), but classes are joined by dots in CSS selectors (as individual classes), not with spaces (as though it were a string). In your case it would be `h1.h1.mb-0.text-gray-800`. Much of that (including the element type) probably isn't needed, though. Of course, you could always just create your own class (i.e. `.text-centered-mobile`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any columns? If no then you can use the grid system of bootstrap to center text. That way you don't have to use media queries because boostrap has its on way of making content responsive. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
Bootstrap has some very useful documentation.